# In swift2, is it possible to assign a tuple with 2 elements to 2 variables where one is a constant and one can be mutated

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, swift2, tuples

In the following example, the xcode compiler has a warning on the first line:
Variable 'y' was never mutated, consider changing to let constant.

```
while var (x,y) = stack.tryPop() {
  // .. x is mutated
  x++

 // y is not mutated
}

// in Stack struct:
func tryPop -> (x:Int,y:Int)? {}
```

However if I change the var to let, as follows:

```
while let (x,y) = stack.tryPop() {
```

... then I get a compiler error: Cannot pass immutable value to mutating operator: 'x' is a 'let' constant.

Of course, I can safely use var instead of let, and ignore the compiler warning, but I would like to know if there is a way of getting around the warning by specifying that x is mutating and y is constant, when assigning from a tuple?

Comment: Do you use the value of y?  If not you can use `var (x,_)`

Comment: Good idea, but I do require the value of y

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with Swift pattern matching:

```
while case (var x, let y)? = stack.tryPop() {
    // .. x is mutated
    x++

    // y is not mutated
}
```

You can read more about Swift Patterns [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID419)